# Javascript fetch not reading JSON file

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, fetch

I am using ES6 and Fetch.

It's giving me this error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

Here is the code:

```
  fetch('list.json').then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  }).then(function(j) {

    console.log(j);
  });
```

and here is the data from list.json:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "name1"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "name2"
  }
]
```

Why I'm I getting this error and how can I fix this?

Comment: The response is not a JSON but html. Probably an error message. Look in the console.

Comment: My guess is that the server is returning an  error in the form of an HTML page. Can you check the response you get? (e.g. Networking tab in Chrome Dev Tools)

Comment: It seems that fetch is getting an HTML file, do you have a 404 HTML file or something like that?

Comment: When I console.log(response); It's saying TYPE: is Basic

Comment: That's not a valid JSON. JSON should always start with curly braces.

Comment: Don't forget your `fetch` can fail. You need to handle that case. `fetch("list.json").then(response => response.ok ? response.json() : Promise.reject(response.statusText)).then(json => console.log(json)).catch(e => console.error(e));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a valid JSON file. Valid JSON would be like this

```
{
  "data":[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "name1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "name2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending a JSON which is being understood by the .json method correctly, you should just cast it in the mentioned manner and everything should be good to go.

Correct JSON:

```
{ "products" : [
  { "Name": "Cheese", "Price" : 2.50, "Location": "Refrigerated foods"},
  { "Name": "Crisps", "Price" : 3, "Location": "the Snack isle"},
  { "Name": "Pizza", "Price" : 4, "Location": "Refrigerated foods"},
  { "Name": "Chocolate", "Price" : 1.50, "Location": "the Snack isle"},
  { "Name": "Self-raising flour", "Price" : 1.50, "Location": "Home baking"},
  { "Name": "Ground almonds", "Price" : 3, "Location": "Home baking"}
]}
```